# Send response to server with data on receiving GCM push notification on Android device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented GCM push notifications for my Android app.
Now I want to send some data to server as response to the notification back to the php server.
How to do that?

Comment: open your activity when click on notification or if come from notification than call some webservice i think u got

Comment: i think u have r gcm receivere when receive gcm call some webservice

Comment: Share Your GCM Receiver Code to understand Better??